# Brauer–Nesbitt theorem -- Does Finite-dimensionality matter?

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups, galois-representations

The Brauer–Nesbitt theorem that many literatures cite is stated as follows:

**(BS.1)**: Let $KG$ be a group algebra of a *finite* group $G$ over a field $K$. Let $M,N$ be $KG$-modules. Suppose [*A condition that will be quoted later*], then $M$ and $N$ have the same composition factors iff for each $g \in G$, the matrices $M(g), N(g)$ have the same characteristic roots (counted according to their multiplicities).

This is quoted from (30.16) of:

> **[1]**  Charles W. Curtis, Irving Reiner - *Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras* -John Wiley & Sons Inc (1962)

However, there is another Brauer–Nesbitt theorem that I met:

**(BS.2)** Two Galois representations $\rho, \rho^{\prime}: G_K \rightarrow GL_n(L)$ have isomorphic semisimplifications if and only $\rho(g), \rho^{\prime}(g)$ have the same characteristic polynomials for each $g \in G_K$. [Other claims omitted.]

This is quoted from (2.5) of this note, whose author said that this is **(BS.1)**.

> **[2]**  [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~tsg/Index_files/ArizonaWinterSchool2013.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Etsg/Index_files/ArizonaWinterSchool2013.pdf)

**Question 1**: Since the absolute Galois group is **profinite** (not necessarily finite), how can we directly apply **(BS.1)** to show **(BS.2)**?

**My attempts**: I have read the proof quite thoroughly and feel that the **finite-dimensionality** of the group algebra $KG$ is essential. The finiteness is used to show that the characters of simple $FG$-modules are linearly independent, when $FG$ is split over $F$. (I used the Wedderburn-Artin Theorem to prove the linear independence)

I have also found a "purely algebraic" result on this, which seems to be quite broad:

**(BS.3)**: Let $k$ be any field and $A$ a $k$-algebra. Let $M, N$ be two $A$-modules
which are finite-dimensional as $k$-vector spaces. If for all $a \in A$, the characteristic polynomials on $M$ and $N$ are equal, then $M$ and $N$ have the same composition factors.

We see that **(BS.2)** is a direct corollary of **(BS.3)**. This is quoted from this note:

> **[3]** [https://math.uni.lu/~wiese/notes/GalRep.pdf](https://math.uni.lu/%7Ewiese/notes/GalRep.pdf)

**Question 2**: In [3], the proof is essentially the same as the one in [1]. But in [3], the author said that "**For this question we may and do assume that $A$ is a semisimple finite dimensional k-algebra**". It seems that this claim is a gaint leap for me! If $A$ *were* a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, I know that by quotient out the Jacobson radical, $A$ could indeed be assumed as semisimple. BUT again, **why can we assume that $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$-algebra?**

Sorry for such a lengthy post, and sincerely hope that someone may help me out! Thank you for commenting or answering!

P.S. The condition omitted in **(BS.1)** in the braket "[]":

> there exists an extension field $L$ of $K$ such that $L$ is a splitting field for $G$, with the property that if $V$ is a completely reducible $KG$-module, then $V^L$ is a completely reducible $LG$-module. (We may take $L=K$ if $K$ is already a splitting field.)

Comment: Hey Hetong. Have you read this: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/EggermontMaster.pdf Specifically Theorem 5.40?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you so much! I shall read that! :)

Comment: Did you find that useful?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I read some parts of that a few days ago and found that quite useful! Yet it seems that the Theorem 5.40 is under the condition that the characteristic of the base field $k$ is zero. This is enough for me now. Thank you so much! While for $\mathrm{char}(k)=p>0$ case, I may turn to that later on. :)

Comment: That's good. Note though that to extend to positive characteristic you just need to upgrade from traces to characteristic polynomial equality. Anyways, you can either answer your own question, or I can submit an answer to get this off the unanswered list.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Maybe you can submit an answer by just copying the link above, so I can upvote and accept the answer. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the OK of the OP, I'm just going to turn my comment into an answer.

The question that he is after is answered in Theorem 5.40 of [this](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/eggermontmaster.pdf) ([Waybackup](https://web.archive.org/web/20231107234151/https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/eggermontmaster.pdf)).

Comment: Link rot. Here's the new location: https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/eggermontmaster.pdf